# Flow chart node/edge from diamond

Tags: tikz-pgf, flow-charts

I am trying to make a flow chart in tikz, however I am unable to create node/path from my decision/diamond to process correctly. I am trying to create path from west of my decision box to process, however it is drawing node from top (circled red in figure).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\title{TikZ based Block Diagrams}
\author{Ralph}
\date{July 2016}

\usepackage{bytefield}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{todonotes}


\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.7}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,shapes.geometric,arrows,3d,calc,fit,shadows,decorations,automata,backgrounds,petri,positioning,decorations.pathreplacing,matrix}

\usepackage{xargs}

\newcommandx*{\includetikz}[3][1=\linewidth,2=0.3\linewidth]{
 \newlength{\fwidth}
 \setlength{\fwidth}{#1}
 \newlength{\fheight}
 \setlength{\fheight}{#2}
 \input{#3}
 \global\let\fwidth\undefined
 \global\let\fheight\undefined
}

\tikzstyle{line} = [draw, -latex',execute at begin node=\scriptsize]
\tikzstyle{startstop} = [rectangle, rounded corners, minimum width=2cm, minimum height=1cm,text centered, draw=black, fill=white!30]
\tikzstyle{io} = [trapezium, trapezium left angle=70, trapezium right angle=110, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw=black, fill=white!30]
\tikzstyle{process} = [rectangle, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw=black, fill=white!30]
\tikzstyle{foralarmm} = [rectangle, minimum width=2cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw=black, fill=white!30]
\tikzstyle{decision} = [diamond, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw=black, fill=white!30]
\tikzstyle{arrow} = [thick,->,>=stealth]



\tikzset{
  blueBlock/.style={rectangle, draw=blue, thick, text width=4.25em, text centered, minimum height=3em},
  greenArrow/.style={draw=green, thick, -latex',execute at begin node=\tiny},
  greenDashArrow/.style={draw=green, thick, dashed, -latex',execute at begin node=\tiny},
  redArrow/.style={draw=red, thick, -latex',execute at begin node=\tiny},
  greenLine/.style={draw=green, thick, execute at begin node=\tiny},
  redLine/.style={draw=red, thick, execute at begin node=\tiny},
  terminalPt/.style={coordinate},
  database/.style={draw,
      cylinder,
      cylinder uses custom fill,
      %cylinder body fill=yellow!50,
      %cylinder end fill=yellow!50,
      shape border rotate=90,
      minimum height=2.0cm,minimum width=1.5cm,
      aspect=0.25
    }
  } 

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\autoref{fig:flowchartTest} shows the flowchart.
\begin{figure}[htb]
  \centering
  \includetikz{testFlowChart.tikz}
  \caption{Flow chart}
  \label{fig:flowchartTest}
\end{figure}

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{references}
\end{document}






\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=3cm]

\node (start) [startstop] {Start};

\node (setup)  [process, below of=start] {Setup};
\node (compute)  [process, below of=setup] 
{\begin{tabular}{c}
    Compute xyz\\ 
\end{tabular}};
\node (test) [decision, below of=compute,node distance=4cm] {\begin{tabular}{c}
    is computed xyz\\true?\\ 
\end{tabular}};
\node (displace)  [process, below of=test,node distance=4cm] {Displace};
\node (detect)  [process, below of=displace,node distance=3cm] {Detect};
\node (testdetection)   [decision,right of=detect,node distance=6cm] {detected?};
\node (acqir)   [process, right of=testdetection,node distance=5.5cm] {Acquire klmn};
\node (end)   [process, below of=acqir,node distance=3cm] {Apply abc};
\path [line] (start) -- (setup);
\path [line] (setup) -- (compute);
\path [line] (compute) -- (test);
\path [line] (test) |- node [anchor=east, text centered,text width=4em] {No} (compute);
\path [line] (test) -- (displace);
\path [line] (displace) -- (detect);
\path [line] (detect) -- (testdetection);
\path [line] (testdetection) |- node [above,auto,text centered,text width=4em] {No} (compute);
\path [line] (testdetection) -- node [auto, text centered,text width=4em] {Yes} (acqir);
\path [line] (acqir) -- (end);

\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image: Flowchart]

Comment: Welcome to TeX. SE! Please complete your code so, that we can test it. At least add your nodes style definitions.

Comment: @Zarko thanks for pointing out, I have updated it

Comment: Please check again, what you upload. It seems to be more documents. Make from your document Minimal Working example (MWE) which would contain only those packages, which are essential for drawing flowchart,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume, that you expect something like this:

[image]

I'm sorry but I had to say: in preparation of above picture your code not helped me at all. It is actually miracle if you can with it obtain showed picture in your question ... So I wrote new MWE from scratch, where I try to use similar names for node style.

```
\documentclass[tikz,
               border=5mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, chains, positioning, quotes, shapes.geometric}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
    node distance = 8mm and 20mm,
      start chain = going below,
     arrow/.style = {thick,-stealth},
      base/.style = {% common features of all nodes
            draw, thick, 
            minimum width=30mm, minimum height=10mm, align=center,
            inner sep=1mm, outer sep=0mm,
            on chain, join=by arrow},
  decision/.style = {diamond, base,
            aspect=1.5, inner xsep=0mm},
   process/.style = {rectangle, base},
 startstop/.style = {rectangle, rounded corners, base},
                        ]
\node (start)   [startstop] {Start};
\node (setup)   [process]   {Setup};
\node (compute) [process]   {Compute xyz};
\node (test)    [decision]  {is computed xyz\\true?};
\node (displace)[process]   {Displace};
\node (detect)  [process]   {Detect};
\node (testdetect)   [decision,right=of detect]  {detected?};
\node (acqir)   [process,right=of testdetect]    {Acquire klmn};
\node (end)     [process]   {Apply abc};
% connection lines not considered by "join"
\draw [arrow,red] (test.west) to["No" '] + (-1,0) |-  (compute.west);
\draw [arrow] (testdetect) |- node [near start,right] {No} (compute);
\path   (testdetect) to["Yes"] (acqir);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Above code is designed as Minimal Working Example (MWE). Please, in future questions take it as example, how to write it (it contain only necessary packages and style definitions).

MWE is relatively sophisticated and very concise, so if you have question about some detail, don't hesitate to ask.